# Error while exporting the worksheet as a csv file - Getting Runtime error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm using this code to export the worksheet as a CSV:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()
Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False      'Possibly overwrite without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\tmp\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

When I provide this location:

```
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\tmp\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

It gives me error:

```
Runtime 1004
```

But when I change the location to:

```
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

It works!

Can anyone please tell me what to do in this case?

Comment: You probably do not have permission to put files in that folder.

Comment: @ScottCraner I need to others to use this file to export the results using the above Macro. If I provide this location: ="C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.csv" Then its restricting to my machine. But the other users will be running the Macro in their machine. Can I change the location in any way or can I/other users get permissions by making any change in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that there is no C:\tmp location and a solution would be for you to create a network drive that all the users that need it have access too and save the CSV there.